Does formal marriage take place after swayamvara?
I read that draupadi was married to pandavas after swayamvara ceremony.What happened in ramayan between rama and seeta?
Are marriage rituals mandatory after swayamvara?
Or woman starts living like wife after swayamvara without rituals?
What do the scriptures say

Conditions of swayamvara are set and announced ( or re-stated ) by the bride's father before hand in the swayamvara and her public demonstrated choice ( by garlanding the bridegroom) is mandatorily accepted as final by the bridegroom,their party and other hopefuls attending the function in this mode of marriage.
Marriage mantras and blessings are part of the ritual, may be optionally repeated at the place of the bridegroom as a celebration by his relatives.

Can you mention the source sir?

Although my ancestors knew Sanskrit, I and many like us  have lost the good opportunity to learn our base literature compelled by influence of English and sadly .. Sanskrit original texts are not always accessible, even if   available in some places in India ... I request other scholar contributors to dig out valid Sanskrit references from the Scriptures about this topic of ancient royal practice.
